# Replace a few different elements in the string and return it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string and I want change some words.
I write next function. If a word to change is alone in my string, this work normal. But if that words more then one it change only last.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="main-arr">How are you my friend?</div>
  <div id="main-arr__last"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

var sometext = $('#main-arr').text();
var someArr = sometext.split(' ');

for ( var i = 0; i < someArr.length; i++ ) {
    if ( someArr[i] === 'you' || someArr[i] === 'he' || someArr[i] === 'she' ) {
        var newArr1 = someArr.slice(0, i);
        var newArr2 = someArr.slice(i + 1, someArr.length);
        newArr1 = newArr1.join(' ');
        newArr2 = newArr2.join(' ');
        var word = 'error!';
        console.log(newArr1);
        console.log(newArr2);
        $('#main-arr__last').html(newArr1 + '<span class="red">' + ' ' + word + ' ' + '</span>' + newArr2);
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Why don't you use a regex and replace function ?

Answer (score 0):

The function is not changing only the last word. The problem is that every time you replace a word you replace the html in `#main-arr__last` too.

Here is a better solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sometext = $('#main-arr').text();
    sometext = replaceAll(sometext, ' you ', ' error! ');
    sometext = replaceAll(sometext, ' he ', ' error! ');
    sometext = replaceAll(sometext, ' she ', ' error! ');

    var someHtml = toHtml(sometext, 'red');

    $('#main-arr__last').html(someHtml);
});

function replaceAll(str, search, replacement){
    return str.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
}

function toHtml(str, clazz){
    return replaceAll(str, 'error!', '<span class="' + clazz + '">error!</span>');
}
```

First we implement a `function replaceAll` to replace all occurrence of a word in a text, after that we have the text with all the words, you, he and she, in our case, replaced by error!.

Then we implemented the `function toHtml` to involve all 'error!' word in a span with a determined class passed as a parameter.